# Android Studio: Add an activity to mobile (Material design)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio, material-design

I have a question about theme for Android app in Android Studio. When I'm creating a new project I would like to have an material design theme, but I don't get this activity theme to choose.

On first picture you can see my view for adding an activity and on second picture what I would like to have.

*My current view*

[image: My current theme]

*Material design view*

[image: Material design theme]

Does anyone have a solution how to set up Android Studio so I can have a view which is showed on second picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this question.

To have this Project Template (Material design) available in Project Wizard, you need to have Android Studio version 1.4 or above.

For details see this link: [Android Studio 1.4 Release](http://android-developers.blogspot.hr/2015/09/android-studio-14.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don' t know if my as show that in the wizard. Bit materiale is a style. And this style is a guide line recommend by google. So you can make your app with material design also writing the code. For example you can use a floating action button, or a combo of beautiful color or pit simple animations inside yours views or using cards in listview.

Answer (score 0):

If you have latest updated Android API, `SDK`, then you will get the material design by default; even if you would not use wizard for adding an activity.

Comment: I have installed API 22 (Lollipop) but screen from first picture to add activity to model is still showing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm barking up the wrong tree here, but just for reference, here are the Android SDK components I've got installed:

[image]

Here is the buildscript, android and dependency sections of my build.gradle:

[image]
[image]
[image]

And last but not least, Android Studio version:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
If you couldn't find the tool fix, you can anyway inherit your activity from appcompactactivity. 
And change your androidmanifest as follows to get material design feel
 <application
       //your stuff
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Don't forget to add the following depenency in build.gradle and sync

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'